# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: php, http, ssl, https

tengo una duda, quiero redireccionar mi website desde PHP nativo de HTTP a HTTPS e intente lo tradicional

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?minegocio\.mx
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.minegocio.mx/$1 [R,L]
```

pero no funciona, alguien que me pudiera colaborar?

***No es wordpress***

Me sale esto en el CPanel:

**Note: You do not have a dedicated IP address. As a result, web browsers that do not support SNI will probably give false security warnings to your users when they access any of your SSL websites. Microsoft® Internet Explorer™ on Windows XP™ is the most widely used web browser that does not support SNI.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola amigo prueba el siguiente codigo el cual realiza una redireccion 301.

```html
#Redireccion 301
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.tusitio.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://tusitio.com/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Espero te sea de ayuda.

Comment: gracias por todo amigo!